# How to add token in nuxt axios instanse

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I try to create axios instance and add token header.

```
const apiClient = axios.create({
    baseURL: "..."
});
apiClient.interceptors.request.use(
    (config) => {
        const token = localStorage.getItem("auth._token.local");
        if (token) {
            config.headers["Authorization"] = 'Bearer ' + token;
        }
        return config;
    },
    function(error) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
);
```

But it throw an error localStorage is not defined.
I think the error throw because I use it in fetch hook on page, but there is no localStorage on server-side. How should I modify my code?

Answer (score 0):

If this piece of code is indeed inside fetch, as you say, you are correct. fetch is called first on the server, so there is no localStorage because you have no localStorage API without a browser.

You could use nuxt's context to check whether you are on the client or the server like:

```
// Client-side
if (process.client) {
    // ...your code checking for localhost
} else {
    // do whatever fallback on the server side....
}
```

more info:
https://nuxtjs.org/api/context

Comment: thank you. Maybe you can give me advice, what is a best way to set token header both for client and server request in my case?

Comment: I don't think that will be possible as you only want to authenticate if the token is present (which you will never know on the server...). Maybe you could just get the API data on `beforeMount` or `mounted` hook, which is not executed on the server. That way you just fetch data on the client, and you are sure to have access to check localStorage.